# Changing values of sliced arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

I made a simple array X like this one

```
import numpy as np
X=np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
```

Then I made these two arrays that give me the exact same output by slicing X

```
A=X[:2,:2]
B=X[np.array([0,1])[:,np.newaxis],[0,1]]
```

If I change a value in A like

```
A[1,1]=99
```

then the corresponding value in X also changes to 99.

But if I change a value in B like

```
B[1,1]=100
```

there are no changes in the values of X

What causes this difference between A and B?

Comment: `B` is a copy, created with `advanced indexing`.  Don't skip the fundamental docs about `view` vs copy.